# Java syntax array

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I can never find what that code perform:

```
functionName(new float[]{factor});
```

is it array declaration? I mean:

```
new float[]{factor}
```

it is equal to

```
float[] arrayName = new float[factor];
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new float[]{factor}
```

is just one type of array declarations in **Java**. It creates a new *float array* with factor value in it.

---

Another ways how we can declare arrays:

For **primitive** types:

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[3];
int[] myIntArray = {1,2,3};
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

For **classes**, for example String, it's the same:

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[3];
String[] myStringArray = {"a","b","c"};
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

Source from [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
new float[]{factor}
```

This piece of code creates a `float` array with a single element and that element is `factor`.

---

```
functionName(new float[]{factor});
```

And this means that you're calling the method `functionName()` and passing a single-element `float` array to it, where that single element is `factor`.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are passing an anonymous array to the function as an argument and No, it doesn't mean that `factor` is the `length` of array.
It means:

```
float factor = 0.5f;
float[] array = {factor};
function(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
functionName(new float[]{factor});
```

Calls a function named: `functionName` passing a new array (anonymous) with one element as an argument, which is the contents of `factor`.